# ManyToMany collection keeps getting deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a class with several lazily initialized collections, both `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany`. The `ManyToMany` relationship is unidirectional, so the `Expert` class has no `Project` collection.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "project")
private List<Logging> loggings = new ArrayList<Logging>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "project_expert", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "expert") })
private List<Expert> experts = new ArrayList<Expert>();

public void add(Logging logging) {
    logging.setProject(this);
    this.loggings.add(logging);
}

public void add(Expert expert) {
    this.experts.add(expert);
}
```

To add an object to a `OneToMany` collection, I would do this:

```
Project project = projectService.save(projectForm.getProject());
Logging logging = new Logging();
project.add(logging);
logging = loggingService.save(logging);
```

This works fine. However, when I try to add an element to the `ManyToMany` collection, the collection seems to be deleted upon saving the parent object, so I can never add more than one child object:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newexpert", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String newExpert(@ModelAttribute("projectForm") ProjectForm projectForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

  Project project = projectService.save(projectForm.getProject());
  Expert expert = projectForm.getExpert();
  if (expert != null) {
      project.add(expert);
  }
  project = projectService.save(project);

  return "redirect:/project/" + project.getId();
}
```

This is what the service method looks like (`projectRepository` extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`):

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Project save(Project project) {
    return projectRepository.save(project);
}
```

In the logs I found this:

```
2014-05-01 17:01:49 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1174 - Deleting collection: [test.model.Project.experts#1]
2014-05-01 17:01:49 DEBUG SQL:109 - delete from project_expert where project=?
2014-05-01 17:01:49 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1232 - Done deleting collection
```

**Edit 1:** This is what happens upon `save(projectForm.getProject())`:

```
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Loader:2136 - Loading entity: [test.model.Project#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - select project0_.id as id1_4_1_, ... from Project project0_ left outer join project_expert experts1_ on project0_.id=experts1_.project left outer join Expert expert2_ on experts1_.expert=expert2_.id where project0_.id=?
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Loader:951 - Result set row: 0
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Loader:1485 - Result row: EntityKey[test.model.Expert#2], EntityKey[test.model.Project#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Loader:1305 - Found row of collection: [test.model.Project.experts#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:160 - Resolving associations for [test.model.Project#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:286 - Done materializing entity [test.model.Project#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionLoadContext:232 - 1 collections were found in result set for role: test.model.Project.experts
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionLoadContext:280 - Collection fully initialized: [test.model.Project.experts#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionLoadContext:240 - 1 collections initialized for role: test.model.Project.experts
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Loader:2160 - Done entity load
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:175 - committing
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:149 - Processing flush-time cascades
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:189 - Dirty checking collections
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionEntry:202 - Collection dirty: [test.model.Project.loggings#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionEntry:202 - Collection dirty: [test.model.Project.parties#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionEntry:202 - Collection dirty: [test.model.Project.experts#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Collections:194 - Collection found: [test.model.Project.experts#1], was: [test.model.Project.experts#1] (initialized)
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Collections:201 - Collection found: [test.model.Project.loggings#1], was: [test.model.Project.loggings#1] (uninitialized)
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG Collections:201 - Collection found: [test.model.Project.parties#1], was: [test.model.Project.parties#1] (uninitialized)
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:123 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 3 objects
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:130 - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 3 updates, 0 removals to 3 collections
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG EntityPrinter:114 - Listing entities:
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - test.model.Expert{id=2, ...}
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - test.model.Project{..., id=1, ...}
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG EntityPrinter:121 - test.model.Expert{id=1, ...}
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - select count(id) from Logging where project_id =?
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - select count(id) from Party where project_id =?
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1174 - Deleting collection: [test.model.Project.experts#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - delete from project_expert where project=?
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1232 - Done deleting collection
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:113 - committed JDBC Connection
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG JdbcTransaction:126 - re-enabling autocommit
...
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer:88 - Loading collection: [test.model.Project.loggings#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG SQL:109 - select loggings0_.project_id as project_5_4_0_, loggings0_.id as id1_2_0_, ... from Logging loggings0_ where loggings0_.project_id=?
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG ResultSetProcessorImpl:168 - Preparing collection intializer : [test.model.Project.loggings#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG ResultSetProcessorImpl:127 - Starting ResultSet row #0
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl:77 - Found row of collection: [test.model.Project.loggings#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:160 - Resolving associations for [test.model.Logging#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:286 - Done materializing entity [test.model.Logging#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionLoadContext:232 - 1 collections were found in result set for role: test.model.Project.loggings
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionLoadContext:280 - Collection fully initialized: [test.model.Project.loggings#1]
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG CollectionLoadContext:240 - 1 collections initialized for role: test.model.Project.loggings
2014-05-01 18:30:04 DEBUG AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer:118 - Done loading collection
```

**Edit 2:** Apparently the `ManyToMany` collection in the parent object `projectForm.getProject()` is initialized and empty. How can that be? I expect it to be unitialized, or if it is initialized for some reason, not empty?

Comment: Could you show the `add` method of the `Project` class? This is a polymorphic method, taking either a `Logging` or an `Expert` argument, right? and `projectService.save()` too.

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Change FetchType.LAZY to FetchType.EAGER and see if that at least gives you values inside getProject(). If you declare that object as lazily loaded, Hibernate will initialise an empty collection and won't fill it until you try to use it.

Comment: Chaning to `FetchType.EAGER` does NOT give me any values in `getProject()`, there's just an empty collection. The values are there on database and are displayed fine on the form page.

Comment: Seems that I stuck with a similar problem, did you manage to find any solution

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your service like this:

```
@Transactional
public Project addExperts(Project project, List<Expert> experts){
    List<Expert> projectExperts = project.getExperts();
    for(Expert expert: experts){
        projectExperts.add(expert);
    }

    project.setExperts(projectExperts);
    return project;
}
```

This will encapsulate the fetching of Project.experts inside a Transaction so that the lazily loaded collection can be fetched and initialised properly. By adding the list you have determined in your controller, you can then save the project properly and have the cascade create the new expert objects. I'm pretty sure this should fix your problem.

If you don't see `INSERT` statements creating your `Expert` objects, then thats your problem. Hibernate can't insert a reference to your `Expert` objects into your `JoinTable` if they don't exist in the database, hence why it would delete your collection object.

Comment: In fact, no `Expert` objects are ever created, there's a more or less fixed set in the database. Your suggestion works, but only if I explicitly fetch the project from the database, get its `experts` collection, add the `expert`, and attach the collection to the new `project` object from the controller. In the controller I then call the `save` service and all is well. Is this normal? Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed the collection gets deleted when I just do a save, so had to change the `save` service to first fetch the collection from the database. Anything I can do about this?

Comment: Because your collections are lazily loaded, Hibernate won't pull them out of the database unless you specifically ask it too. You could set your collection as `FetchType.EAGER` so that the collection gets initialised when you get your object out of the database.

Comment: In answer to your first comment too, you shouldn't be doing any of this processing in your controller. All business logic (like fetching existing objects) should be done in your service layer. Make a new method in your service layer to do whatever you need to do. Leave your DAO call method alone so its just `DAO.createOrUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have the culprit.

You're initializing the ManyToMany collection as

```
private List<Expert> experts = new ArrayList<Expert>();
```

and then your `add()` method accesses the collection as `this.experts.add(..)`. Yet the ManyToMany association is `LAZY`. So how would the JPA provider know that you didn't intend to override the collection with a new one instead?

Try changing `add()` with the getter for the collection, as

```
public void add(Expert expert) {
    this.getExperts().add(expert);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I added more logs, as you can see the collection is deleted when I save the object I get back from the form. This object doesn't have any collections initialized, but that doesn't cause the `OneToMany` collections to be overwritten. I assumled it would work for the `ManyToMany` collection as well.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look later. Btw, why do you need `CascadeType.ALL` on your ManyToMany relationship?

Comment: Correct, I don't need `CascadeType.ALL`, will change it.