# How to use a ManyToMany collection with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm really confused about how to use a `@ManyToMany` child collection in my application. To demonstrate my problem I have set up an example project at https://bitbucket.org/ctombaugh/test

The main problem is that the child collection is deleted when I save the parent object. The only way I can think of to circumvent this is to fetch all child collections from database and attach them to the parent object before saving, but I can't believe this is the right way. So I guess I'm doing something wrong, hopefully someone can pinpoint it and improve my understanding of how JPA works.

I would like to mention upfront that this question is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410753/manytomany-collection-keeps-getting-deleted), but I thought it would be best to focus on the core of the problem, remove all context, and work with a clean example project. I hope that's not a problem.

parent object class `Test`

```
@Entity
public final class Test implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private volatile Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "test_label", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "test") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "label") })
    private Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<Label>();

    private volatile String name = "";

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Test test = (Test) o;
        if (!id.equals(test.id)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (id == null) return 0;
        return id.hashCode();
    }

}
```

child object class `Label`

```
@Entity
public final class Label implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private volatile Integer id;

    private volatile String name = "";

    public Label() {
    }

    public Label(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Label label = (Label) o;
        if (!id.equals(label.id)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (id == null) return 0;
        return id.hashCode();
    }

}
```

service `TestServiceImpl`

```
@Service
final class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    private final TestRepository testRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestServiceImpl(TestRepository testRepository) {
        this.testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Test> findAll() {
        return testRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Test save(Test test) {
        return testRepository.save(test);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Test saveAndAdd(Test test, Label label) {
        test = testRepository.save(test);
        test.getLabels().add(label);
        return testRepository.save(test);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Test create() {
        return testRepository.save(new Test());
    }

    @Override
    public Test findOne(Integer id) {
        return testRepository.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

form backing object `TestForm`

```
public class TestForm {

    private Test test;
    private Label label;

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public Label getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

}
```

controller `TestConroller`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    private TestService testService;
    private LabelService labelService;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @Autowired
    TestController(TestService testService, LabelService labelService) {
        this.testService = testService;
        this.labelService = labelService;

        // populate labels
        List<Label> labels = labelService.findAll();
        if (labels == null || labels.size() == 0) {
            labelService.create("label a");
            labelService.create("label b");
        }

    }

    @ModelAttribute("labels")
    public List<Label> getLabels() {
        return labelService.findAll();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public String getUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        return name;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String firstPage(ModelMap model) {
        List<Test> tests = testService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("tests", tests);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addExpert(ModelMap model) {
        testService.create();
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test/{testId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editProject(@PathVariable Integer testId, ModelMap model) {
        TestForm form = new TestForm();
        Test test = testService.findOne(testId);
        form.setTest(test);
        model.addAttribute("testForm", form);
        return "test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitTest(@ModelAttribute("testForm") TestForm testForm, BindingResult result) {
        logger.info("labels: " + testForm.getTest().getLabels());
        if (testForm.getTest().getLabels() != null) {
            logger.info("labels size: " + testForm.getTest().getLabels().size());
        }
        testService.save(testForm.getTest());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/addlabel", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addLabel(@ModelAttribute("testForm") TestForm testForm, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        Test test = testForm.getTest();
        Label label = testForm.getLabel();
        test = testService.saveAndAdd(test, label);
        return "redirect:/test/" + test.getId();
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf template form `test.html`

```html
<form id="testForm" action="#" th:action="@{/test}" th:object="${testForm}" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{test.id}" />

    <p>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" th:field="*{test.name}" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <button id="testbutton" type="submit" name="testbutton">Save</button>
    </p>

    <h4>Labels</h4>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="label : *{test.labels}">
            <td th:text="${label.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${label.name}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p>
        <select id="label" th:field="*{label}">
            <option value="">(select label)</option>
            <option th:each="label : ${labels}"
                    th:value="${label.id}"
                    th:text="${label.name}"></option>
        </select>

        <a href="#" onclick="addLabel();">Add</a>
    </p>
</form>
```

application context `ApplicationContext`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("test.model")
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public StringToLabel stringToLabel;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/**");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/js/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(stringToLabel);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource datasource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
        datasource.setUsername("sa");
        datasource.setPassword("");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource( dataSource() );
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan( new String[ ] { "test.model" } );
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter( vendorAdapter );
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties( this.additionalProperties() );
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                this.entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

}
```

application initializer `ApplicationInitializer`

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);
        rootContext.setDisplayName("Test application");

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("openEntityManagerInViewFilter", OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("singleSession", "true");
        filter.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, "dispatcher");

    }

}
```

**Edit 1:** Apparently I'm not able to intialize any collection in the service (calling `size()` doesn't work). Does this mean the parent object gets detached? This also goes for `OneToMany` collections, but there I am able to add several children by saving the children instead of the parent.

I guess there must be something wrong with my configuration, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: hi , use (cascade = CascadeType.ALL) and let me know the effect.

Comment: Many to Many and any other kind of relationships are from Hibernate/JPA, **not** from Spring at all.

Comment: Karibasappa G C, no effect I'm afraid.

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, I'm using Spring Data JPA and I'm having problems initializing a lazy collection after calling a Spring controller, possible due to incorrect use of Spring transaction management or Spring contexts. So I don't see why I cannot mention the fact that I'm using Spring.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are lazy loading @`ManyToMany` collection, and then merging old detached object with empty children(as children never loaded) into a new session and saving parent. 
And when parent is saved you are also cascading same operation to child which is resulting in deletion as hibernate/jpa assuming you manually removed them and merging the parent.

To avoid this, either eagerly load all children in relationship, or don't cascade merge and manage children independent of parent.

Comment: To manage the children independently, should it be sufficient to just remove cascade? I tried `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` but the collection is still removed when I save a parent.

Comment: Please try this to make the collection just read only?

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "test_label", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "test", insertable=false,updatable=false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "label", insertable=false,updatable=false) })
    private Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<Label>();